# Visual Studio unable to find references when logged in as a different user

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new Web Application project in Visual Studio 2015, just experimenting.  I did it while logged into windows as User1.  It created and built fine.  Then when I logged in as User2, ran the project, and tried to build it, it cannot find all of the references.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction here?  In previous projects I did on VS2012, it saved all of the references files within the project folder, and so anyone who logged in could access the refences, but now it seems to be saving them in the user folder of whoever created the project.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Did you save the projects in User1's document folder? One user doesn't have permission to read/modify another user's folder.

Comment: No, the project is saved onto a folder directly on the C drive called TestProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try run Visual Studio with Administrative privileges. Right click on VS icon and Run As Administrator. Hope this will solve the issue.